# What happens when a battery is in space?

Tags: electric-current, space, batteries

What would happen If you take a battery in a space ? Would the current flow between terminals being it in vacuum of space?

Comment: Of course.  Batteries do not rely on the outside atmosphere or pressure for proper functioning.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it stems from insufficient effort by the author.  All questions like "What would happen if I <abc> with <xyz>?" are off topic when the answer is "Nothing unusual or unexpected.".

Comment: Is there resistance in space ?

Comment: No there is not air resistance in space.

Comment: but there is electrical resistance, since it's mechanism doesn't require air or gravity at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [this post](http://spaceplace.nasa.gov/batteries/en/) over at NASA. It's directed towards kids but it gives a good overview.

Most relevantly,

"In space, batteries must work in both very hot and very cold conditions. They must withstand a lot of radiation from the Sun. They must work in a vacuum without leaking or blowing up! They must be rugged enough to withstand the severe vibrations of a rocket launch."

So batteries would function normally, but there are some special conditions that have to be considered when manufacturing batteries for use in space.

To answer your question in the comments of your question:

Yes there is electrical resistance in space. That resistance is a property of the circuitry not the environment the circuit is in (normally).